# I can't get the desired ouput with print and str.center

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to print a designer door mat but I can't get the desired result. The mat should only contains these **| , - , .** special chars.
Here N is number of rows where as M is width of it. In between it should print Welcome.

My Code:

```
N, M = 4, 12
for i in range(1, N, 2):
    print(str(".|." * i).center(M, '-'))
print("WELCOME".center(M, '-'))
for i in range(N-2, -1, -2):
    print(str(".|." * i).center(M,"-"))
```

My result:

```
----.|.-----
-.|..|..|.--
--WELCOME---
---.|..|.---
------------
```

Desired output:

```
----.|.-----
-.|..|..|.--
--WELCOME---
-.|..|..|.--
----.|.-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier to build up the top piece, print that along with the welcome, then print the reversed of top for your bottom bit?

```
N, M = 4, 12
top = [('.|.' * i).center(M, '-') for i in range(1, N, 2)]
print(*top, 'WELCOME'.center(M, '-'), *top[::-1], sep='\n')
```

Gives you:

```
----.|.-----
-.|..|..|.--
--WELCOME---
-.|..|..|.--
----.|.-----
```

What's a little more explicit instead of using list slicing is to use `reversed` here that's functionally the same but reads easier, eg:

```
print(*top, 'WELCOME'.center(M, '-'), *reversed(top), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Can I know what `*top[::-1]` represents? What is `*top`?

Comment: It's called "unpacking"... so top in this case is a list of two elements... the `top[::-1]` reverses the order of top.... so the function call to print effectively becomes (in this case) `print(top[0], top[1], 'WELCOME.center(M, '-'), top[1], top[0])` and the `sep='\n'` puts a newline between all of those 5 items instead of a space...

Comment: can I know what went wrong with my second for loop? I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: @sai_636 `range(N-2, -1, -2)` isn't the natural inverse of `range(1, N, 2)` for `".|." * i`... while I think you *could* adjust that - it still makes more sense to just produce it once forwards and then use the same in reverse order instead of generating things twice...

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()
lst = s.split();
n = int(lst[0])
m = int(lst[1])

s= ['.|.','WELCOME'] 
n1 = (n-1)//2

for i in range(1,2*n1, 2):
    print((s[0]*i).center(m, '-'))

print(s[1].center(m,'-'))

for i in range(((2*n1)-1), 0,-2):
    print((s[0]*i).center(m, '-'))
```